# List column logic

Tags: php

I have a bunch of list items and I want to arrange them into 3 columns, alphabetically from top to bottom, left to right. This is easy enough to do by dividing the total amount of items by 3 and spitting them out. The other thing I need to do though is to keep the amount of items in each column even, starting at 4 per column.

Example:

```
A    E    I
B    F    J
C    G    K
D    H    L
```

So if there were <= 4 items, it would just be 1 column

```
A    
B        
C        
D
```

The 5th item would start column 2 and the 9th would start column 3.

If there are > 12 items, it always adds it to the end of the rightmost column, starting a new row if the other columns have equal amounts of rows. Still maintaining alpha sort order.

So for 14:

```
A    F    K
B    G    L
C    H    M
D    I    N
E    J
```

And 16:

```
A    G    L
B    H    M
C    I    N
D    J    O
E    K    P
F
```

I'm doing this on the server side and loading up 3 arrays (one for each column) so for 16 items it would be:

```
$left_col = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$mid_col = array('G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K');
$right_col = array('L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P');
```

I want to keep this logic on the server side (PHP) rather than handle it with Javascript.

Comment: Is it possible to store them in 1 array, rather than 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (you can even change `MIN_ROWS` and `NB_COLUMNS`):

```
<?php

define('MIN_ROWS', 4);
define('NB_COLUMNS', 3);

function store_to_columns($array)
{
  $count = count($array);

  $result = array();

  if ($count <= MIN_ROWS * NB_COLUMNS)
  {
    foreach($array as $i => $element)
    {
      $current_column = floor($i / MIN_ROWS);

      if (!isset($result[$current_column]))
        $result[$current_column] = array();

      $result[$current_column][] = $element;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $current_column = 0;
    $nb_cells = 0;

    foreach($array as $i => $element)
    {
      if (!isset($result[$current_column]))
        $result[$current_column] = array();

      $result[$current_column][] = $element;

      $nb_cells++;

      if ($nb_cells >= floor(($count + NB_COLUMNS - $current_column - 1) / NB_COLUMNS))
      {
        $nb_cells = 0;
        $current_column++;
      }
    }
  }

  return $result;
}

print_r(store_to_columns(range('A', 'D')));
print_r(store_to_columns(range('A', 'L')));
print_r(store_to_columns(range('A', 'N')));
print_r(store_to_columns(range('A', 'P')));
print_r(store_to_columns(range('A', 'Z')));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your question is "how do I do this such that it scales," one way to do that is using a combination of `floor` and `mod`.

```
<?php

$myArray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);

$minEntriesPerCol = floor(count($myArray)/3);
$extras =  count($myArray) % $minEntriesPerCol;
$cols   = array();
$begin  = 0;
$end    = 0;

for($n=1; $n<=3; $n++)
{
    // start where we were last time, increment by 1
    $begin  = $end + 1;
    // remove the 1 we just added, add another array, add an extra if needed
    $end    = $begin - 1 + $minEntriesPerCol + ($extras > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    // remove an extra every time; doesn't matter if it's less than 0
    $extras = $extras - 1;

    // the -1 and +1 is because arrays start from 0, not 1
    $cols[$n] = array_slice($myArray, $begin-1, $end-$begin+1);
}

print_r($cols)

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not that great as others but it works:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');

 /**
  * Changes array to columns
  * 
  * @param <mixed[]> Array
  * @param <int> step, try cominging with it ;)
  * 
  * @return <mixed[][]>
  */
 function arrayToColumns($array, $max)
 {
     $num = count($array);

     $temp = array();

     for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
     {
         $temp[$i % $max][] = $array[$i];
     }
     return $temp;   
 }

 /**
  * Prints columns
  * 
  * @param <mixed[]> arrayToColumns result
  */
 function printColumns($arrays)
 {
     foreach($arrays as $array)
     {
        # Do whatever you want with that array
         echo implode("\t", $array) . '<br/>';
     }
 }

 echo '<pre>';
 printcolumns(arrayToColumns($arr, 2));
 echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Code above will result: (with `$max = 2`)

```
a   c   e   g
b   d   f
```

Result when `$max = 4`

```
a   e
b   f
c   g
d
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you like to scape using of array!

This is a sample code I wrote. It can do that job without using 3 array...

```
$test_array = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T");
$cols_no = 3;
$rows_no = ceil(count($test_array)/$cols_no);

if ($rows_no<4) $rows_no=4;

echo "<table>";
for ($row_counter=0;$row_counter<$rows_no;$row_counter++){
    $index1 = $row_counter;
    $index2 = $row_counter+$rows_no;
    $index3 = $row_counter+($rows_no*2);

    echo "<tr>\n";
    for ($col_counter=0;$col_counter<$cols_no;$col_counter++){
        $index = $row_counter+($rows_no*$col_counter);

        if(!empty($test_array[$index])) 
            echo "<td>$test_array[$index]</td>\n";
        else 
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the total amount by the number of columns you have (in this case, 3). Then use `floor()` on that value to find out how many items are going to in each column. You need to use `floor()` because otherwise, take 17/3 = 5.666, which could give you 6 base per column, instead of 5. Store this value in say, array[0] for column 1, array[1] for column 2, etc, so

```
$base = floor($tot / $cols);

for($i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++);
    $colamount[$i] = $base;
```

Then, take the total number of items, and subtract the number of columns times the number of base items in each column. Using the previous example, we would have 17 - (floor(17/3) * 3) = 17 - 15 = 2. This is the amount of elements that are not assigned to a column yet.

```
$remainder = $tot - ($base * $cols);
```

Then loop through, adding one to the left most column, then to the next one, until no remainder is left, IE (since remained will always be less that $cols, we can be safe knowing we wont go out of bounds)

```
for($i = 0; $i < $remainder; $i)
    $colamount[$i]++;
```

This will assign the left overs as needed, from left to right. Then simply loop through the array as needed to render your lists, such as

```
$itemindex = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++)
{
    $list[$i] = "<ul>";

    for($o = 0; $o < $colamount[$i]; $o++)
    {
        $list[$i] .= "<li> { $items[$itemindex] } </li>";
        $itemindex++;
    }

    $list[$i] .= "</ul>";
}
```

And the finished lists should be in $list[0], $list[1], etc from left to right.